# Ignore code blocks in Golang test coverage calculation

Tags: unit-testing, go, code-coverage

I am writing unit tests for my golang code, and there are a couple methods that I would like to be ignored when coverage is calculated. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I don't know a way. You can get profiles by function with -func (see http://blog.golang.org/cover or run `go tool cover -help`), but that's different. You could write "tests" that exercise that code but don't really test anything, but that doesn't seem great.

Comment: Yea, it doesn't seem that there is a way to test the code, but ignore it in coverage reports... :/

Answer (score 19):

One way to do it would be to put the functions you don't want tested in a separate go file, and use a build tag to keep it from being included during tests. For example, I do this sometimes with applications where I have a `main.go` file with the main function, maybe a usage function, etc., that don't get tested. Then you can add a test tag or something, like `go test -v -cover -tags test` and the main might look something like:

```
//+build !test

package main

func main() {
    // do stuff
}

func usage() {
    // show some usage info
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to do the same without the need of a tag, i.e. by default?

Comment: @OlegSklyar No, I don't believe you can do the same without the tag. The coverage report goes by all the code.

Comment: And the **blank line** after the `//+build test` comment is important. `+build comment must appear before package clause and be followed by a blank line`

Comment: I've also discovered that the tag names cannot have a dash in them: `unit-tests` won't work, whereas `unit_tests` will.